# Programmatically stretch window across available vertical space in winforms

Tags: winforms

How can I make a Winforms window stretch from the top of the screen to the bottom but not over the Taskbar?

I'm looking for an end result similar to the snap feature in Win 7, but would like it in XP and Vista too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `System.Windows.Forms.Screen` it contains all the information you need to do this, primarily the `GetWorkingArea` function.

Comment: Thanks Doggett - it's easy when you know how ;)